# Match VS2013 C++ struct packing to old MSVC++ compiler version?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2013

I am trying to wrap an unmanaged C++ library (compiled using MSVC++ compiler version 13, dating from 2002 or 2003) in a CLI C++ console application (using Visual Studio 2013), in order to eventually call it from a C# project.

I have managed to get my wrapper building and running, but from the results I get when it runs I suspect VS2013's C++ compiler is packing its stucts differently from how the unmanaged library is reading them.

Is there a  way to tell VS2013 to package its structs in the same way the version 13 compiler would? Or do I have to find the old comipler and write an intermediate wrapper that exposes only basic, unpacked types?

Comment: Use `/d1reportSingleClassLayoutMyClass` to get the compiler to print the class layout for `MyClass`.  Use [`#pragma pack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx) to set structure packing (or `#pragma pack(show)` to print the current packing at compile-time).  If this class type uses C++ features (inheritance, virtual functions, etc.) or has data members that use C++ features, then sharing the class across files compiled with different versions of the compiler is not supported.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis OK, so thanks to those I have a neat little graph of the struct (doesn't look like there's anything C++-specific in there) and I now know that the pack is set to 8. I assume these are the details 2013 is using. Is there a way I can see what struct layout/pack is "baked in" to the precompiled libs/dlls I am linking, so I can know for sure that that is the issue?